# How can I have the effect of default parameter with variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am hitting this problem for some time now and I can't figure out how to solve it. The context is a reflection system in c++. A slim down explication of the problem is this. I have those 2 structs. One is to represent multiple parents of the type ClassType and the other would represent and Orphan class (a class of ClassType type and without parents)

```
template<typename ClassType, typename... ParentTypeList>
struct Parents 
{
};

template<typename ClassType>
struct Parents<ClassType>
{        
};
```

Then in the declaration of my classes to be reflected i use this macro, the class ReflectionHelper::Parents are the classes above

```
#define DEFINE_METACLASS(className, ...) \
private: \
typedef className SelfType; \
typedef ReflectionHelper::Parents<SelfType, __VA_ARGS__ > ParentList \
```

A usage of an orphan class it would be:

```
class TestMetaClassDefine
{
DEFINE_METACLASS(TestMetaClassDefine);     
};
```

Now the problem is that the __VA_ARGS__ is empty and the

```
typedef ReflectionHelper::Parents<SelfType, __VA_ARGS__ > ParentList;
```

is thus not valid.

One way I thought of solving this is to have default template arguments but it is not allowed with variadic template.

Anybody have a technique to resolve this problem?

Thanks alot

Comment: I haven't fleshed it out at all, but could you have a dummy `Orphan` type that you could provide in this case, then specialize `Parents<SelfType, Orphan>` to behave however you want orphans to behave?  That gives you an argument to provide to the variadic macro so everything works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCC preprocessor allows for a special syntax that elides the final comma in a variadic macro argument list if the list is empty:

```
#define MACRO(arg, ...) foo(arg, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

This exapands:

```
MACRO(a,b)   ->  foo(a, b)
MACRO(a)     ->  foo(a )
```

You can use this for your `DEFINE_METACLASS` macro to cover all cases at once.

*Update:* As @Dennis says, you can use your original syntax in MSVC++ and it won't even produce a trailing comma.

Comment: I believe MSVC supports a similar extension.

Comment: @Dennis: Cool, post it if you have details! (Although MSVC lacks variadic templates :-) .)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415(v=vs.80).aspx Looks like that behavior is automatic in MSVC, but according to the comments, it also supports that syntax as a form of gcc compatability.  So once it *does* support variadic templates, this syntax will work on both compilers as a non-standard extension.